# Maximum length for a fully qualified quoted object name

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I would like to get confirmation on the maximum length of a fully qualified SQL Server object name.

*Please vote on the answer below if you agree. (I won't get points for these votes)*

<s>Currently I worked out the following:</s>

- The datatype should be `nvarchar`
- The fully qualified object name is `<Server>.<Database>.<Schema>.<Object>`
- Each part can have 128 characters (`sysname = nvarchar(128)`)
- `quotename()` of a 128 character string is maximum `(128*2)+2` (each character escaped + open and close square brackets)
- each name part gets separated by a `.`

This makes `(((128*2)+2)*4)+3 = 1035`

From that I derive the formula: `(((128*2)+2)*@nr_of_name_parts)+(@nr_of_name_parts-1)`

I think the formula is correct because plugging in 3 parts ends up with 776 which happens to be the param length of the sp_recompile procedure

Comment: And `sp_rename` has a parameter of length `1035`, so it seems valid.

Comment: I think you should break this up into a simple question and an answer. Waiting for up votes and down votes to confirm your reasoning. Or other contradictionary answers.

Comment: Yep. Looks correct to me.

Comment: @Mikael Ok, I will put my reasoning in an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(Answering my on question as community wiki, based on the comment of Mikael Eriksson)*

- The datatype should be nvarchar
- The fully qualified object name is `<Server>.<Database>.<Schema>.<Object>`
- Each part can have 128 characters (sysname = `nvarchar(128)`)
- `quotename()` of a 128 character string is maximum `(128*2)+2` (each character escaped + open and close square brackets)
- each name part gets separated by a `.`

This makes `(((128*2)+2)*4)+3 = 1035`

From that I derive the formula: `(((128*2)+2)*@nr_of_name_parts)+(@nr_of_name_parts-1)`

I think the formula is correct because plugging in 3 parts ends up with 776 which happens to be the param length of the `sp_recompile` procedure

Comment: If the original name had square brackets like [bob] this will get escaped as [[bob]]]. Therefore you calculation is off by 4 characters.

Comment: No it is not. 128 * 2 = escape every character in an 128 character long object name + 2 for the open and close square bracket.

Comment: If the long name actually includes includes open closing square brackets the quotename added 3 characters not two. quotename('[bob]') = '[[bob]]]'

Comment: The opening [ is not escaped. Compare the results of this `select len(quotename(replicate(']', 128))) as ']', len(quotename(replicate('[', 128))) as '['`